# Issue with Aggregate Function

Tags: r, aggregate

Part of my data is of the following:

```
   JOINING_DATE  STU_ID
    01/01/2016  Neu19567
    01/04/2016  Neu00170
    01/04/2016  Neu00170
    01/04/2016  Neu02561
    01/04/2016  Neu02561
```

Now I want my results as:

```
  JOINING_DATE STU_ID
    01/01/2016  1
    01/04/2016  4
```

i.e, I do not want to uniquely count the number of STU_IDs. What I want is to calculate the number of rows/observations against each JOINING_DATE.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
Pre <- aggregate(data = df, dfA$STU_ID ~ df$JOINING_DATE, function(x) length(unique(x)) )
```

However, I am getting a unique count rather than total obs:

```
 JOINING_DATE STU_ID
01/01/2016  1
01/04/2016  3
```

What I am doing wrong, and how can I rectify it? Thanks

Comment: cant you just use `table(df$JOINING_DATE)`?

Comment: if you use the `data=df`, you do not have to use the `df$` syntax before the variable name. There may be a typo in your command; try: `aggregate(data = df, STU_ID ~ JOINING_DATE, function(x) length(unique(x)) )`

Comment: This would be simpler: `aggregate(STU_ID ~ JOINING_DATE, data = df, length)`.

Comment: @KenS.: This works for a singular column, but I did not want to use that due to performance issues of added operations.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: This worked. Thanks